# Parallel robot framework tests via locust

Tags: robotframework, load-testing, locust

We are trying to run the automation tests written in robot framework in parallel using locust.

As of now, we have been able to run the robot-framework test file through locust by using the robot-framework's [robot](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.html) package.

#### Code

#### 1. Locust Script

```py
import robot
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):

    wait_time = between(0.1, 0.2)

    @task
    def robot_parallel_test(self):

        robot.run('robot_test1.robot')
```

#### 2. Robot Framework test script (robot_test1.robot)

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${URL}              http://www.google.com
${BROWSER}          Chrome
${search_form}      css=form[name=f]
${search_query}     css=input[name=q]
${search_term}      RobotFramework

*** Test Cases ***
Google Search
    Open Browser    ${URL}   ${BROWSER}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${search_form}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${search_query}
    Input Text      ${search_query}   ${EMPTY}
    Input Text      ${search_query}   ${search_term}
    Submit Form
```

When we run the locust script, is starts running the robot framework tests by opening instances of **Chrome** and executing the automation. The problem here is that while one automation script is running, locust opens another instance of chrome which affects the previously running robot test cases and all tests fail.

We have tried running the tests in **headless** mode but they still fail if another test runs while the current test is running.

We are looking for a way to run our robot automation tests in parallel through locust so that they keep on running in parallel and do not disrupt each other flows, so that we can load test our application with concurrent users.

There is a library [pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) which helps run robot scripts in parallel but we are trying to achieve this via locust.

Comment: Why do you wanna use locust for that? why don't you directly spawn your robot test run with gevent like locust does?. Because you will not get any metric from your locust tasks. I see no reason to use locust here to run robotframework.

Comment: We have been asked to hook robot framework with locust, thats why were looking into this possibility. 
I agree with your point that running robot tests in locust tasks will not be able to provide us any metrics.
Being new to python, can we you please elaborate a bit more or direct us on how to use gevent to spawn our robot tests.

Answer (score 2):

Use pabot for parallel robot tests:
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot

Comment: Yes, we are aware of pabot, we were looking to achieve behavior with locust.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need locust integration for this parallelism. It's just about to use some async library like gevent (used by locust) to do something like this:

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
from gevent.pool import Group

import robot


def robot_parallel_test(self):
    robot.run('robot_test1.robot')

greenlets_group = Group()
workers = 5
for index in range(workers):
    greenlets_group.add(gevent.spawn(robot_parallel_test))

greenlets_group.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. will look into that direction. The above approach didn't work though as it runs the scripts sequentially.

Comment: Sure, happy to help!

Comment: @TheAssassin what did you ended up with? How things went with gevent?

Comment: @Wlad We experienced some issues with gevent maybe because we didn't had the required expertise in it. we ended up using `pabot library` to run robot tests in parallel.